# How to install plugin through arelleCmdline.py

Tags: python, ubuntu, plugins, xbrl

I am unable to download the efm-extended-pragmatic-all-years plugin for --disclosureSystem

I am not having any trouble regarding installation my problem basically revolves around installation/download of a plugin in arelle.

The library that I'm using is [Arelle](https://github.com/Arelle/Arelle).

My terminal input

```
python arelleCmdLine.py -f ../0000050863/2016/10-K/0000050863-16-000105-xbrl.zip --plugins EdgarRendererAllReports --disclosureSystem efm-extended-pragmatic-all-years -r ../0000050863/
```

The output that I'm getting:

```
[info] Activation of plug-in Edgar Renderer All Reports supplement successful, version 0.9. - EdgarRendererAllReports 
[arelle:disclosureSystemName] Disclosure System "efm-extended-pragmatic-all-years" not recognized (a plug-in may be needed). - 
[info] loaded in 3.07 secs at 2019-06-05T06:20:30 - /home/ubuntu/0000050863/2016/10-K/0000050863-16-000105-xbrl.zip/intc-20151226.xml
```

Basically, I am supposed to get an XLSX file named Financial_report.xlsx upon using the above disclosure system plugin. Moreover, I'm using python3.6.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you need the EFM validation plugin too.  Try changing the `--plugins` option to:

```
--plugins 'EdgarRendererAllReports|validate/EFM'
```

Comment: it's not the ultimate solution but it did point me in the right direction.

Comment: What were the other issues?